# How to print a number with localized thousands AND decimal separators?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I expected to find an easy answer for this, but for some reason I did not. I need to print a number with a thousands separator (dot) and a decimal separator (comma). For example: if the input is 10000, the output should be 10.000,00.

If tried:

```
>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.UTF-8')
>> f'{num:,.2f}'
'10,000.00'
>> f'{num:n}'
'10.000'
```

And other variations, but I couldn't understand how to use the dot as the thousands separator and the comma as the decimal separator without using .replace(), for example.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It probably depends on your underlying C functions.  Look up the documentation for those.

Comment: You need a local that does what you want. use de_DE.UTF-8 or something like that.

Comment: Thanks, @G.Anderson. The pt_BR works too, but I needed to use the locale.format_string() instead of f'{num:,.2f}'. Solved it =)